# How to prove that the set $\{x|x|,x^2\}$ is linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

If we use Wronskian determinant to solve this set $\{x|x|,x^2\}$ we get the answer of determinant to be $0$ which means this set is linearly dependent. But I need to prove the same without using Wronskian method. How should I do this?

I've done something like, taken $2$ scalars $a$ and $b$ such that $ax|x| + bx^2=0$ and tried to show that the solution for this equation will be non-trivial which means the set is linearly dependent but I failed. Can someone show me how I should approach this without using Wronskian method.

Comment: A set of two vectors is linearly dependent if and only if the two vectors are scalar multiples of each other. This is not the case here.

Comment: Yes it did, thank you. @Martin

Comment: Regarding your first sentence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian#The_Wronskian_and_linear_independence

Comment: Use `\{` and `\}` to write $\{$ and $\}$ in math equations.

Comment: @HansLundmark This cleared up my doubt, thank you.

Comment: I tried a lot to put } but it wasn't registering, turns out I was doing it wrong, I'll remember this. @jjagmath